# Why is :not(p) seemingly selecting <p> tags?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My HTML is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>hiya</p>
<h1>this is h1</h1>
<h2>this is h2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

My stylsheet.css is this:

```
:not(p)
{
color:#ff0000;
}
```

Yet *everything* is red, including `<p>`. I've tried Firefox 20, Internet Explorer 10, and Chrome. It doesn't seem to get any more basic than this, but I can't figure out why this isn't working (preventing `<p>` from being red, that is). Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: i think, in css u use body { color: red } in  stylesheet.css

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`:not(p)` matches `body`.

The default `color` value is `inherit`.

`p` has no style set.

`p` is therefore inheriting its colour from `body`, which is red.

Solutions: explicity define what you want to be red, OR explicitly set a different colour for `p` (ie. don't use `:not`), OR use `:not(body):not(p)`

Comment: Note, in real CSS OP might need to loosen up that selector to be `:not(body) :not(p)`.

Comment: `:not(body):not(p)` doesn't work (on Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/jBjZ2/ because Chrome thinks that `<html>` can have style too and elements can inherit from it too.

Comment: @Passerby `:not(html):not(body):not(p)`, naturally.

Comment: Actually, `:not(:matches(html,body,p))` may end up being better.

Comment: @Kolink: That would be `:not(html, body, p)`. It's actually not valid to nest `:matches()` within `:not()`, precisely because it would be redundant.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you! I'm reading HTML5 for Masterminds. Either I'm not a mastermind or this book has some explaining to do...

Comment: @BoltClock Fair point - I forgot that `,` is allowed within `:not()`

Comment: @Passerby: `html` must be styleable, it's required by CSS.

Comment: So why not `body :not(p)`?  Seems to me that would skip `html` and `body`.

Comment: @cHao: That would be better, actually. Is your second comment for me? I'm the only one who used the word "redundant" here, but I'm referring to Kolink's comment about level 4 selectors, and not his answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: Kolink had made a comment about it being redundant, but that's apparently gone.  Guess there's no need for the reply to stay.  :)

Comment: @cHao: Ah OK. Should have looked :)

Comment: A great answer, but there’s a terminological inaccuracy in “The default `color` value is `inherit`.” The initial value of `color` “depends on user agent” by the spec, and there is normally no browser default for it, except for `body`. This means that in this case, the `p` children of `body` inherit the value `red` – but because these elements have no setting for `color` in any stylesheet.

Answer (score 7):

This looks it is because you have not defined a specific style for p tag. So :not(p) applies even to body element and inherited.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate id for the `<p>`  and you can use `not` in css.

HTML

```
<p class="hiya" id="hiya">hiya</p>
<p class="hi" id="hi">hi</p>
<h1>this is h1</h1>
<h2>this is h2</h2>
```

CSS

`p:not(#hiya)
{
color:#ff0000;
}`

This will produce the output red color for the `<p>` except the `<p>` with the id "hiya".